# Tracing all threads spawned by a process

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, ptrace

I am struggling to understand the behaviour of ptrace when the treaced process t1 invoke clone() and fork () and spawns another thread t2. According to the documentation t1 is stopped by the kernel via SIGSTOP signal, while the tracer start tracing t2. 
When t2 process will continue? How it will be waken up? 
Let's consider the situation in which I have a pool of threads, and I want to monitor them. if more then one thread is executed in the same time, how can I can I trace them?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to trace - are you single-stepping the code, or doing something else?

Comment: http://progsch.net/wordpress/?p=81 maybe helpful..

Comment: I want to trace every system call invoked by the program and its children.